# problematic sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following query which is running slow:

```
 WITH AcdTran
     AS (select SequenceNo,
                ReqID,
                PolNumber,
                transaction_id,
                application_data,
                trans_type,
                retries,
                status,
                direction
         from   dbo.acord_transaction_benchmark with (nolock)
         where  direction = 'OUT')
select top 1 *
from   AcdTran a
where  a.transaction_id = (select top 1 transaction_id
                           from   AcdTran b
                           where  b.PolNumber = a.PolNumber
                           order  by ReqID,
                                     SequenceNo,
                                     transaction_id)
       and ( status = 'New'
              or status = 'Resubmit' )
       and retries > 0
```

How can i optimize this? To run faster?

Thank you

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Your `select top 1 *` is missing an `order by`

Comment: It should select a single record with status New or Resubmit from a table in sequential order. So , if i have 2 records for a certain PolNumber, and 1 has Sequence 1 and the other has Sequence 2 it should pickup the one with Sequence 1

Comment: OK this is just a standard `greatest-n-per-group` query then I think. There are 3 approaches [evaluated here](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/departments/optimizing-top-n-per-group-queries). The best one to use depends on your indexes and data distribution.

Comment: you probably already have that but make sure you put indices on right columns. It has a great impact on these sort of queries

Answer (score 2):

Should be faster with windowing function ROW_NUMBER:

```
 WITH AcdTran AS (
         SELECT SequenceNo,
                ReqID,
                PolNumber,
                transaction_id,
                application_data,
                trans_type,
                retries,
                status,
                direction,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY transaction_id ORDER BY ReqID, SequenceNo, transaction_id) N
           FROM dbo.acord_transaction_benchmark with (nolock)
          WHERE direction = 'OUT')
SELECT *
  FROM AcdTran
 WHERE (status = 'New'
            OR status = 'Resubmit')
       AND retries > 0
       AND N = 1;
```

As I don't have your table structure nor any data, I obviously didn't test it so you may have to modify the query a bit, but you have the idea.

Comment: @JustMe - Can you supply some example data and desired results.

Comment: JustMe: My mistake, it should be `PARTITION BY transaction_id`, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

What if you pulled out your sub-query into a join:

```
WITH AcdTran
     AS (select SequenceNo,
                ReqID,
                PolNumber,
                transaction_id,
                application_data,
                trans_type,
                retries,
                status,
                direction
         from   dbo.acord_transaction_benchmark with (nolock)
         where  direction = 'OUT')
select top 1 *
from   AcdTran a
inner join AcdTran b on a.SequenceNo = b.SequenceNo --or whatever the PK is
where a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id and
      a.PolNumber = b.PolNumber and
      (a.status = 'New' or a.status = 'Resubmit' ) and
      a.retries > 0
order by b.ReqID,
         b.SequenceNo,
         b.transaction_id
```